# Java8 - List of Integer values print Matching with 1 result showing 1 matching values

Tags: java, filter, java-8, predicate, steam

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(10,15,8,49,25,98,98,32,15,212,401,8,001);
```

Output:-
10,15,15,212,401,001

Using java 8 stream api find number matching with 1 each number.

Any one answering the question.

```
List<Integer> result =  myList.stream().filter(e -> e == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "find number matching with 1 each number."?

Comment: `001` means octal number, not decimal.

Comment: did you mean, that string representation contains `1`?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Convert each number to text. Examine the code point of each character in that text. Look for any match to 49, the code point of the character of the digit “1”.

```java
List.of ( 10 , 15 , 8 , 49 , 25 , 98 , 98 , 32 , 15 , 212 , 401 , 8 , 1 )
        .stream ( )
        .filter (
                ( Integer integer ) -> integer.toString ( ).codePoints ( ).anyMatch ( ( int codePoint ) -> codePoint == 49 )  // 49 is the code point for the character of the digit one, “1”. 
        )
        .toList ( )
        .toString ( )
```

See this [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/j8j1QA).

> [10, 15, 15, 212, 401, 1]

## Filtering for digit `1`

Apparently you want to filter for numbers which contain `1` as a digit in any position.

Convert each number to text. Examine each character by inspecting its Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number. If that code point is the code point for the digit 1’s character, we have a hit.

The character for digit `1` is [code point 49](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) decimal, U+0031 [hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), named DIGIT ONE. See [official Unicode chart](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/charts/CodeCharts.pdf).

```
"1".codePointAt ( 0 ) ⇒ 49
```

Your last value `001` must be a typo. Leading zero means an octal number rather than decimal number in Java syntax.

```java
List < Integer > inputs = List.of ( 10 , 15 , 8 , 49 , 25 , 98 , 98 , 32 , 15 , 212 , 401 , 8 , 1 );

List < Integer > containsDigitOne =
        inputs
                .stream ( )
                .filter (
                        ( Integer integer ) ->
                                integer
                                        .toString ( )
                                        .codePoints ( )
                                        .anyMatch ( ( int codePoint ) -> codePoint == 49 )  // 49 is the code point for the character of the digit one, “1”. 
                )
                .toList ( );
```

> containsDigitOne.toString() = [10, 15, 15, 212, 401, 1]

Comment: Why don’t you use just `'1'`? Then, you don’t need to explain where the `49` comes from.

Comment: @Holger Because I am deliberately teaching the use of  code point integers, and avoiding the `char` type.

Comment: For any printable character expressible as `char` literal, the char literal is equal to the codepoint. There’s no reason no to use them. Writing `49` instead, will not create codepoint awareness. Or just use `integer.toString().contains("1")`. That idiom will even work with characters spanning multiple codepoints.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Predicate<Integer>`

`Predicate<Integer> containsOne = (integer) -> integer.toString().contains("1");`

2. Filter the stream based on the predicate, and use print as a terminal operation to kick off the stream.
   `myList.stream.filter(containsOne).forEach(System.out::println);`